# How to create proxy server in ruby that accepts HTTPS

Tags: ruby, proxy-server

I am looking at this example  to create proxy server
https://gist.github.com/torsten/74107

How do i make it to support https. Any help?

Comment: If there is any way using Webrick

Comment: If you have already got it working for `http`, what happens when you use port `443` and change `HTTP` to `HTTPS`